# How can I partially overwrite the EIP in order to bypass ASLR?

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, aslr

As far as I know, it is possible to overwrite the unchanged part of the EIP to bypass ASLR protection. Unfortunately, I do not understand how this can help me in order to jump to the location of my exploit. I would need the address of a [JMP ESP] instruction in order to do so, but since the address will always vary, what's the idea behind partially overwriting the EIP?

Furthermore, this [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/20502/104194) states that a non-ASLR module is required. How can some parts of the address be fixed and some change in a non-ASLR module?

Comment: Related to [Why are some DLLs not randomized? What makes it hard to deploy full ASLR for all DLLs](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42283/why-are-some-dlls-not-randomized-what-makes-it-hard-to-deploy-full-aslr-for-all)

Comment: Partial EIP overwrite means you have found that only a part of the bytes of EIP are randomized, i.e. can't be overwritten since they keep getting randomized. Thus cutting down the total brute force space to attack ASLR . I.E guess the place to jump to in memory. With a little google I found http://ly0n.me/2015/07/30/bypass-aslr-with-partial-eip-overwrite/

Answer (score 1):

With ASLR not the full address of instructions will vary but only some higher bytes. So for example Byte 1+2 are static but Byte 3+4 not. So the idea behind partially overwriting the EIP is to overwrite only the static bytes of an address to get a (limited) control of the execution flow.